# Opensource graphing solution for C#

Tags: c#, .net, graph

Does anyone know of a good graphing solution for C# that is easy to use and flexible?

Any opinions?

I mainly will need to make graphs like these

[image]

Comment: That looks like a turbo efficiency graph. Or what is it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use this [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question but [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) provides a good solution but don't forget the [Microsoft Chart](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) components, while not OSS they are free.

Comment: Why is it subjective? The image specifies what the library must be able to do.

Comment: "Good", "Easy to use", "Flexible"... all subjective terms. One man's "Good, easy to use, flexible" solution is another's nightmare of pain and difficulty. "Opinion" is absolutely subjective. I'm surprised you asked that.

Comment: Still. Look at the image. not all can free libraries can create that image.

Comment: That's true, however, the criteria are still subjective.